# List of figures empty?

Tags: table-of-contents

My list of figures is empty.

I have in the preamble (I don't know if it's relevant):

```
\newfloat{figure}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{figure}{Figure}

\begin{document}

...

\listoffigures{figure}{List of Figures}

...

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{../north_coast.eps}
       \caption{Map of the North Coast Region.\label{fig:North Coast Region}}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a) `figure` is a standard float environment, so why define it anew? b) You *did* compile at least two times, didn't you? c) Always try to provide a compilable example.

Comment: Another thing: Dont use the `center` environment inside floats: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Comment: @ lockstep: I have just changed the center thing. Very useful indeed. a) I don't know?; b) of course! like hundred times; c) not sure how to do that.
@ Simon: About the \label{}: I do have it!

Comment: Ad a) If you don't know what `\newfloat` and `\floatname` does, try to delete these lines, compile again and look for the difference.